# What is the idiomatic form of the expression 'did you come from upstairs'

Tags: phrase-usage

Let's say I am in a building with multiple floors, I see my friend in the lobby and I want to ask him

> Did you come from upstairs? or
>
> Are you coming from upstairs (if I know he has just come.)

I did not find any google phrase search result when I looked it up, so I am not sure if it is idiomatic or not.

On the other hand, I always hear the phrase

> Are you going downstairs/upstairs?

So I think it is perfectly idiomatic.

Answer (score 2):

@emi - good clarification. ( I noticed your post in chat and came over here. I tutored English to German speakers (Hamburg & Berlin) for many years. )

@Tim - the 'continuous' form is often challenging to translate.  You are right in this case to use the simple:

> Are you going downstairs/upstairs?

The continuous form (*) is used for things happening in the moment, placed within the verb tense time frame:

> I am running.
>
> I was running.
>
> I have been running (all day, so I'm really tired). :)

Here's an instance where it might happen using your example question.

Lets say there's a fire and a lot of smoke in that building. The firemen have been in there a little bit, but can't see each other well. One fireman sees the other on the stairs, but doesn't know which way the other has gone. He might radio:

> Are you coming from upstairs ?

Asking indirectly "have you been up there ? Do we need to search there ? " Or "which way do we go next ? "   But he'd probably just ask:

> Anything up there ?

Here's a trick to remembering this:  think of *running water.*

Statement of an ultimate fact using present tense: Water runs.  (It's the nature of water :)

Statement of a condition in the passing moment: The water is running (now).  (Oops, you forgot to turn the water off :))

---

(* in German it's something like "verlaufsform" ? - Laufen = run. But German, like many languages, does not have a continuous form. )

Comment: I don't think OP is German but I guess his native language does also lack progressive tense.